# Get absolute position of a SVG element

Tags: javascript, html, svg, svg.js

Suppose this snippet code with `svg.js`

```
var g1 = draw.group();
var g2 = g1.group();
g2.move(100,100);
var g3 = g2.group();
g3.rect(200,200);
```

Now, how i can get the absolute position of this `rect`?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `rbox` function, which takes the translations into account.

Here is an example:

```
var draw = SVG('paper');
var g1 = draw.group();
var g2 = g1.group();
g2.move(100,100);
var g3 = g2.group();
var rect = g3.rect(200,200);

console.log(rect.rbox());
```

Comment: For anyone stumbling across  this in the future: In svg.js >= v2.5 you need to use `rbox(draw)` to get the coordinates relative to your svg document. Otherwise the box is relative to your document viewport